How to decode this Notam?
I've a difficulty to use the Notam decoder on this Notam.
V0018/24 NOTAMN 
Q) OOMM/QPIAU/I/BO/A/000/999/2336N05816E005 
A) OOMS 
B) 2401250001 
C) 2405160001 
E) [US DOD PROCEDURAL NOTAM] INSTRUMENT APPROACH PROCEDURE NOT AUTHORIZED ILS RWY 08L.

Also what is US DOD in this context?


V0018/24 NOTAMN Q) OOMM/QPIAU/I/BO/A/000/999/2336N05816E005 A) OOMS B) 2401250001 C) 2405160001 E) [US DOD PROCEDURAL NOTAM] INSTRUMENT APPROACH PROCEDURE NOT AUTHORIZED ILS RWY 08L

In short

The Notam says the IFR approach for ILS RWY 08L at Muscat International Airport (Oman) is not allowed until 16/05/2024 00:01 UTC.

US DOD ➫ US Department of Defense. The DoD issues this Noram because there is an agreement allowing the United States, which have an important naval base in Oman, to use Oman's Muscat military airfields.



How to decode

V0018/2024 NOTAM ➫ Notam reference, N ➫ New Notam
Q ➫ Always Q

OOMM ➫ Related to Muscat control center (Oman)
QPIAU ➫ Instrument procedure is not available (Q ➫ QCode, PI ➫ Instrument approach procedure, AU ➫ Unavailable)
I ➫ IFR
BO ➫ Purpose: B ➫ Immediate attention, O ➫ flight operations
A ➫ Scope is the aerodrome
000/999 ➫ From sea level to unlimited
2336N05816E005 ➫ Center position is 23°36'N 058°16'E, radius 5NM (this is the reference point of the aerodrome)


A field ➫ Location, aerodrome or FIR, OOMS ➫ Muscat International Airport (Oman)
B field ➫ Beginning, 2401250001 ➫ Valid from 25/01/2024 00:01 UTC
C field ➫ End, 2405160001 ➫ Valid to 16/05/2024 00:01 UTC
E field ➫ Notam text, [US DOD PROCEDURAL NOTAM] INSTRUMENT APPROACH PROCEDURE NOT AUTHORIZED ILS RWY 08L

US DoD Notams are aimed to military and civil crews
It is a procedural Notam part of FLIP, issued by US DoD using DINS (which is interfaced with the AFTN). FLIP is a special information/documentation/mapping system provided by US agencies for foreign airfields. It is used by US military and also civil pilots via a subscription. This Notam is part of FLIP:

[...] Foreign civil/military flight crews who use US DoD FLIP should access DoD procedural NOTAM (V series) or DoD chart/FLIP/DAFIF NOTAM (W series). V/W series NOTAMs are available via:

Primary or secondary DINS Query websites.
Aeronautical Fixed Telecommunication
Network (AFTN),
[...]


(Source)

Most of this information can be decoded online.

US Department of Defense. This is alerting DoD aircrews that they may not fly this procedure.

It does make me wonder if Oman has put out a matching civil NOTAM for that ILS at Muscat...

A DoD procedure NOTAM does not have to be against a military procedure. Rather, it is issued when DoD aircrews may not use that procedure published in FLIP, as mins explained in his answer.

Yeah, I asked my question because I'm wondering if the issue is that the procedure somehow is nonconformant with US DoD standards in a way that renders it unflyable for DoD users but isn't an issue for civil air traffic, or if the procedure is NA because, say, the localizer transmitter is INOP, meaning that it's not usable for civil traffic either and Oman would have a civil NOTAM out saying that civil users can't fly the procedure either

DoD will not write a NOTAM against a procedure if the host nation has already written one.
While it is possible that a procedure does not conform to US standards, the likely result would be that it is not published in FLIP in the first place.

Let me also say that this should not be a DoD procedure NOTAM, since it is not a DoD procedure. Rather, the NOTAM should be a DoD FLIP and DAFIF one. It’s nuanced, but the DoD is not the procedure design authority.

Thanks -- that's the insight I was missing, that DoD won't NOTAM a procedure that the host nation's already NOTAMed.  It really does make me wonder what's wrong with the underlying procedure and its supporting NAVAIDs though...like, an ILS is an ILS is an ILS pretty much no matter where you go, no?

@UnrecognizedFallingObject, it’s possible that the procedure in DoD FLIP is out of date, so the office of primary responsibility writes a NOTAM until they can review & update the procedure in FLIP. That’s why I think this isn’t really a procedural NOTAM. That’s the speculation on my part.
